# FIrebase Cloud Messaging, cannot resolve dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to write an application using Firebase Cloud Messaging as per the guidelines given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites), but I'm struck in adding the dependency for implementing FCM (com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2). Every time I try to add it via project structure, it won't list the dependency in the search results. When I try to add it in app level gradle, it gives me an error that the dependency cannot be resolved. I don't know where I'm going wrong but please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you check its prerequisites points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download updates from your SDK manager. I had the same issue. Updating **Google play services** and **Google Repository** from the SDK manager worked for me.