# Firebase: Failed To Resolve Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating my first application using Firebase.

I followed step by step to [add firebase in my app.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)

I am getting following errors after I have done all the steps.

[image]

My **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also have added following line in Project level **build.gradle.**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

What are the issues, I couldn't found. Any help?

Comment: Studio Version is **2.1.2** @Shubhank

Comment: gradle version **2.1.2** @RRR

Comment: try to update google repository in your sdk..

Comment: you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499006/firebase-setup-on-android) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501835/gradle-not-compiling-for-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Comment: The guy here had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37699930/1754112

Comment: @PratikButani update repostitory

Comment: Let me try to update Repo., If it will work then I will make it as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks to all, I have updated as suggested links by @RRR and flagged as duplicate :)

Comment: get the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354611/error27-13-failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-8-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update the **Google Repositorty** in **Andriod-SDK** under **Extras**.
Then Sync your project and your project will sync successfully.

Because Firebase 9.0.2 Updated version is under updated Google Repo.

Comment: Thank you. You are also right.

Comment: @Deepak Goyal i m using this and failed to call my service that will generate token  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'